# Dynamically mapping class properties and values from one class to another

Tags: c#, class, dynamic

I have a class name Invoice, but this class is beyond my control
because it comes from another company API where we save our invoice

```
public class InvoiceOutput
{
    public string InvoiceNum {get; set;}
    public string TotalAmount {get; set;}
    public string Date {get; set;}
    public string Address{get; set;}

    public List<InvoiceRows> {get; set;}

    public Add() 
    { 
          //invoice Add functionality
    }
    public bool Save() 
    { 
           //invoice Save functionality
    }


//This is my own Invoice, a copy from all writable properties of InvoiceOutput
public class InvoiceInput
{
    public string InvoiceNum {get; set;}
    public string TotalAmount {get; set;}
    public string Date {get; set;}
    public string Address{get; set;}

    public List<InvoiceRows> {get; set;}
}
```

Now I have an xml being Deserialize to InvoiceInput() class
but the xml file is dynamic in such a way that it may only contain.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Invoices>
  <Invoice>
    <InvoiceNum>0001</InvoiceNum>
    <TotalAmount>5000</TotalAmount>
  </Invoice> 
  <Invoice>
    <InvoiceNum>0002</InvoiceNum>
    <TotalAmount>5000</TotalAmount>
  </Invoice> 
</Invoices>
```

So in this case i want only to assign the values found in InvoiceInput() which I deserialize from xml file to a class list.
So I have my deserialize class now as

```
InvoiceInput[0].InvoiceNum =0001
InvoiceInput[0].TotalAmount=5000

InvoiceInput[1].InvoiceNum =0002
InvoiceInput[1].TotalAmount=8000
```

How can I make it now like this:
assuming I put it under for loop.
Remember that my xml is dynamic so it depends what property is there
so it assigned here.

```
for(int i=0;i<InvoiceOutput.Count; i++)
{
InvoiceOutput.Add();
InvoiceOutput.InvoiceNum  = InvoiceInput[i].InvoiceNum;
InvoiceOutput.TotalAmount = InvoiceInput[i].TotalAmount;
InvoiceOutput.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org) for it.
For example to use:

//Initialize once

```
Mapper.CreateMap<InvoiceInput, InvoiceOutput>();
Mapper.CreateMap<InvoiceOutput, InvoiceInput>();
```

//Using

```
InvoiceInput invoiceInput = Mapper.Map<InvoiceInput>(invoiceOutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to copy the values of the all properties from the class `InvoiceOutput` object to the `InvoiceInput` object.
Then try the reflection based way,

```
    private static object CloneObject(object o)
    {
        Type t = o.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties();

        object p = new InvoiceInput();

        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
        {
            p.GetType().GetProperty(pi.Name).SetValue(p, pi.GetValue(o, null),null);
        }

        return p;
    }
```

Here I am assuming that the property  names are same for the both classes .

[Take a look her for more info.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can then use it as

```
  InvoiceInput b = (InvoiceInput)CloneObject(outp);
```

If you are going to use it frequently then you can try writing it as the [Extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb383977.aspx). And then you can clone all your object just like this,

```
  inputObject.CloneOutputObject(ouputObject);
```

---

**UPDATE**

You can use [Convert.ChangeType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130977.aspx) - it allows you to use runtime information on any IConvertible type to change representation formats. Not all conversions are possible, though, and you may need to write special case logic if you want to support conversions from types that are not IConvertible.

```
      p.GetType().GetProperty(pi.Name).SetValue(p, Convert.ChangeType(pi.GetValue(o, null),YourTypeToConvertTo)),null);
```

to get the your destination property type you can do something like this

```
      PropertyInfo newp = typeof(InvoiceInput).GetProperties().where(x=>x.Name == pi.Name).FirstOrDefault();
```

and then when setting the value

```
      p.GetType().GetProperty(pi.Name).SetValue(p, Convert.ChangeType(pi.GetValue(o, null),newp.PropertyType)),null);
```

Comment: thanks a lot! :-)
I will try this approach.
Yes both class have the same property names. How about if  they  differ on variable type?.